# user settings, from user.config file is not retained after update - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio-2012

software updatation process doesn't retain to older settings. It Creates folder for user.config file. it named them something like this SoftwareName.exe_Url_woktt5kplvmafyzeyiz3pkc3r1f0ywmu. and inside it, another folder named version number ("0.6.585.878) inside there. this is normal behavior.

1) when i update software using installer, it repeats process mentioned above. and creates another folder and don't retain older settings.

2) when i change the AssemblyVersion, and install Software using code, It retains all the setting.

I want installer to retain all the older settings.
So where it can be the problem?  It is happening due to isntaller? or i am missing something in core logic of software update thingy.

Anyone can help quickly, please?.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try to write config into .xml file and maintain it by yourself.